# DynamoDB write operations spike behavior

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Whenever I am doing batch writes, dynamodb will write much more data initially and then it will revert back to provisioned capacity. Is this behavior consistent?

[image]

(For example, in case of EBS, we get write credits which gets accumulated over period of time if unused and we can use all those credits when writing. Is there any such case with dynamodb? )

I understand that I can send messages to SQS and consumer can read from SQS and write to dynamodb, but was just curious about this particular behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called burst capacity:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Bursting

Amazon discourages from relying on this behavior, since burst capacity may not be available at all times.